# linq to sql to returning boolean

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table `Fruits` that contains the following columns

```
UserID | FruitID
```

I want to verify that the UserID is authorized on the FruitID so I'm writing something like this:

```
var IsAuthorized = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
                    where f.UserID == TheUserID && f.FruitID == TheFruitID
                    select f.FruitID).SingleOrDefault();
```

So if the user is authorized the query returns an ID and if he's not authorized, it returns null. I then check to see if the return value is null and then set a bool based on the returned value.

What I want to do is return bool: if the user is authorized then it should return true.

How can I modify the query to return a boolean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var IsAuthorized = from (f in MyDC.Fruits
                         where f.UserID == TheUserID && f.FruitID == TheFruitID
                         select f.FruitID).SingleOrDefault() != null;
```

or if you want this to be done by the underlying LINQ provider (for example if you are using SQL server) you could use the [`.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension method which is better:

```
var IsAuthorized = MyDC
    .Fruits
    .Any(f => f.UserID == TheUserID && f.FruitID == TheFruitID);
```

Comment: The `.Any()` extension method because you won't be retrieving the entire record but the LINQ provider might use an aggregate function.

Comment: `Any` is better, as it's a) more directly what you want, and b) won't bring back data you won't be using.

Comment: Ok, great. Just a quick variation, if I want to test for a list of FruitIDs and a user, it's "where TheFruitIDS.Contains(f.FruitID) && f.UserID == TheUserID"

Comment: can this `any` function used in xml? i am beginner in c#

Answer (score 12):

Any() returns true if the source sequence contains any elements; otherwise, false.

```
var IsAuthorized = from (f in MyDC.Fruits
                             where f.UserID == TheUserID && f.FruitID == TheFruitID
                             select f.FruitID).Any();
```